# Additional sections in ASP.NET web.config file error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-sections

I have legacy ASP.NET web site, upgraded from ASP.NET 2.0 to ASP.NET 4.0 target framework. It's a pity, but the old web.config file uses too many custom sections, positioned on the same level as appSettings.

Web site compiles with error `"Unrecognized configuration section MyCustomSection"`. Is it possible not to refactor all the code and keep the custom config sections in the web.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the MyCustomSection to the configsections?

```
<configSections>
<section name="MyCustomSection"... />
</configSections>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, as this custom sections don't have any type. They are just additional settings grouped by purpose.

Comment: My bad, that's correct solution. I'd missing assembly references.